# paypal not returning any data on success?

Tags: paypal

I have been trying with a simple calling script through post method but on success the paypal is not returning any data like tx,amt,currency stuffs etc..! through which I can confirm the payment and run update query to update invoice status to paid please..!

Here is my code for success page as :

```
<?php

$item_no            = $_GET['item_number'];
$item_transaction   = $_GET['tx']; // Paypal transaction ID
$item_price         = $_GET['amt']; // Paypal received amount
$item_currency      = $_GET['cc']; // Paypal received currency type

$price = '10.00';
$currency='USD';

//Rechecking the product price and currency details
if($item_price==$price && $item_currency==$currency)
{
echo "<h1>Welcome, Guest</h1>";
echo "<h1>Payment Successful</h1>";
}
else
{
echo "<h1>Payment Failed</h1>";
}

?>
```

so if you people can have a look at my code please..!

Answer (score 2):

```
Something is missing in your form here is the form:
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payment">

  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />

  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />

  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="business@test.com" />

      <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="HP LP3065" />

  <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="Product 21" />

  <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="100.00" />

  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="2" />

  <input type="hidden" name="weight_1" value="2" />

      <input type="hidden" name="on0_1" value="Delivery Date" />

  <input type="hidden" name="os0_1" value="2011-04-22" />

          <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Village Cinemas - Adult Vic/Tas Only" />

  <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="Village Cinemas - Adult Vic/Tas Only" />

  <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="10.50" />

  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1" />

  <input type="hidden" name="weight_2" value="0" />

            <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_cart" value="21.05" />

    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />

  <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="First Name" />

  <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Last Name" />

  <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="Address1" />

  <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="" />

  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="City" />

  <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="" />

  <input type="hidden" name="country" value="IN" />

  <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="0" />

  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="email_address" />

  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="en" />

  <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />

  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />

  <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />

  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://domain.com/success" />

  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://domain.com/callback" />

  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://domain.com/checkout" />

  <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale" />

  <input type="submit" name="custom" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here it goes : the data is been return in post form so it can be get through as :

`print_r($_POST);`